# How may I get a list of all groups I belong to in Skype

Tags: windows-8, skype, contacts

For Group (conversations) that are not in my Contacts, how would I get a list of them in Skype? The only way that I've seen so far to know which of these conversations I'm in, is when someone types a message in the Group; this can be a bit unnerving when you are no longer involved in the conversation.

I am using Skype version 6.1.0.129 on Windows 8

I want a list of "Groups" that I am a member of, which have not been added to my Contact list or Favorites. I am looking to remove myself from these groups, but I cannot access them.

Comment: Neither the "Contacts" nor "Recent" will show a group unless you add it to your contacts, some one types in the group, or if you recently interacted with the group. There appears to be no way to view groups that you are a member of, unless one of those three items is true.

Comment: It's quite clear, but let me add more; You can be added to a Group or create a Group to which you are a member. If you do not favorite the Group itself or add the Group to your Contacts, it will not show up and you cannot remove yourself from the Group. Until something happens in the Group with one of the other members.

Comment: I still maintain that "Groups" are entirely localized to your own list.

Comment: I don't think you have experience with this, if it were localized how do I get a list of them? That's at the core of this question!!!

Comment: By "Group", you mean a group conversation?

Comment: Yes, Group conversation; ill update the question

Comment: this is a good question. it's a pity nobody can answer this

Comment: @Ramhound What you are talking about are called "lists", i.e. contact lists, in Skype (they were called "groups" in Messenger). In Skype, "groups" mean group conversations (for group chats and conference calls). Anyway the best the asker can do is: First, go to **View** menu and click on *Show Hidden Conversations* (if it is enabled). Then go to **Recent** tab, and click on *Show earlier messages* (at the bottom). It will lengthen the list and then you can look for groups that are now inactive. Do note that even if you left a group, you can only hide it. You cannot delete it.

Comment: In an effort not to be pinged by people who don't realize this is a 2 year old question I have removed my previous comments.  I know how Skype works I don't need **anyone** telling me how it works or how to do anything in it.

Answer (score -1):

Open this on your computer. It should show you a list of all the huntgroups you are a member of.
https://SKYPEWEBSERVERNAME@DOMAIN/RgsClients/Tab.aspx

Comment: Skype is not the same as Skype for Business. It does not run on an accessible domain and it does not present a web server.